# How get dimension of a Control after Autosize in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How to I get the dimensions of a Control if it's using AutoSize? As I have a Panel and I need to know it's Width after it's auto re-sized and PanelName.Width only seems to give the original width.

This is with a Visual C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should give you an actual value, also you can subscribe for SizeChanged event of a control and get actual value in its handler.

Comment: Also any check done after OnPaint() of the control will return actual size. I use it in an old program where language translation is live and control size is crucial.